# external table with partition elimination

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to understand how to create an external table that supports partition elimination.  I can create a view with a column derived using the filepath function, but that can't be used by Spark.  I can create an external table using create external table as select, but that gives me a copy of the data.  [This article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop#folder-partition-elimination) implies it can be done.

> The native external tables in Synapse pools are able to ignore the
> files placed in the folders that are not relevant for the queries. If
> your files are stored in a folder hierarchy (for example -
> /year=2020/month=03/day=16) and the values for year, month, and day
> are exposed as the columns, the queries that contain filters like
> year=2020 will read the files only from the subfolders placed within
> the year=2020 folder. The files and folders placed in other folders
> (year=2021 or year=2022) will be ignored in this query. This
> elimination is known as partition elimination.
>
> The folder partition elimination is available in the native external
> tables that are synchronized from the Synapse Spark pools. If you have
> partitioned data set and you would like to leverage the partition
> elimination with the external tables that you create, use the
> partitioned views instead of the external tables.

So, how do you expose those partition directories as columns in an external table?